# Is there a way to make Altium populate existing Offsheet Connectors with sheet numbers?

Tags: altium

We inherited a 20 page schematic with sheet-to-sheet connectivity entirely based on net labels.
So if pin 1 of U1 on page 1has a netlabel called START and pin 20 of U200 on page 20 of the schematic has a netlabel called START, then pin 1 is connected to pin 20 on page 20. And if there is a net label on page 11 called START, then the net is connected there too.

Imagine having to debug using this schematic and no prior familiarity with the schematic.

I know, its incredibly bad. For the sake of the technicians, something must be done.

What is the best way to detect nets that travel beyond 1 page so that we can manually place sheet to sheet connectors

Can a script be made to prepend the text of the sheet-to-sheet connector with the page number of the first occurrence.

Comment: Does this address your question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/285168/change-all-off-sheet-connectors-to-ports

Comment: Use ports instead of offsheet connectors. It can add references during annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The net needs to be the same on all pages if it isn't hierarchical. If it is hierarchical then you could create a net label to each page (you technically could do the same thing with a non-hierarchical design but you would need to create net-ties to tie two net names together which would be bad because net ties need to also be created in the PCB which would mean a PCB redesign).

You could create a hierarchical design and label the nets with the sheet numbers manually, you can create a script but in my experience unless you are doing this with many designs it would probably be easier and less time consuming to relabel the design as a hierarchical design than it would be to write a script.

Another thing I would consider: place text on the outside of the net name of the page(s) to he net goes to like the example below. Yes, it would take some time, but the alternatives also would take an equal amount of time.

[image]

Another option would be to give the techs an alitum viewer (free), and teach them how to use ctrl+f

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions!